# How to hide a modal using a function in class components in React

Tags: reactjs

I am working on a React project, In my project I have two components Users and UsersModal.

In Users component Create User button is there when I click that button UsersModal form has to

Appear. So for that I have imported UsersModal component to Users component. Now initially I need

Not to show UsersModal form so please tell me how to write a function to initially close that

Component.

This is Users.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Users.css';
import { Container, Row, Col, Button } from 'reactstrap';
import UsersModal from '../../Components/UsersModal/UsersModal';

class Users extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {

        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Container>
                <Row>
                    <Col>
                        <div className='mt-3'>
                            <Button outline color="secondary">Create User</Button>
                            <UsersModal></UsersModal>
                        </div>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            </Container>
        )
    }
}

export default Users
```

This is UsersModal.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './UsersModal.css';
import {
    Button,
    Col,
    Modal,
    ModalBody,
    ModalFooter,
    ModalHeader,
    Row,
    FormGroup,
    Label,
    Input,
} from 'reactstrap';

class UsersModal extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Row>
                <Col md="6" sm="6" xs="6">

                    <Modal isOpen={true}
                    >
                        <ModalHeader >Create User</ModalHeader>
                        <ModalBody>
                            <FormGroup>
                                <Label for="exampleName">Name</Label>
                                <Input
                                    type='text'
                                    name='name'
                                    placeholder='Enter Your name'
                                />

                            </FormGroup>
                            <FormGroup>
                                <Label for="exampleEmail">Email</Label>
                                <Input
                                    type='email'
                                    name='email'
                                    placeholder="Enter Your email"
                                />
                            </FormGroup>
                        </ModalBody>
                        <ModalFooter>
                            <Button color="secondary">
                                Cancel
                </Button>
                            <Button type="submit" color="primary">
                                Submit
                </Button>
                        </ModalFooter>
                    </Modal>
                </Col>
            </Row>
        )
    }
}

export default UsersModal
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your User component, you need to set a variable which will be used to show and hide the modal -

`toggleUserModal` function is used to either hide or show the modal, on button click it will show the modal by setting `isModalOpen` to true, and you can pass this function to `UsersModal` via `onClose` props, so that you can close the modal by clicking a button in `UsersModal` itself.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Users.css';
import { Container, Row, Col, Button } from 'reactstrap';
import UsersModal from '../../Components/UsersModal/UsersModal';

class Users extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
            isModalOpen: false, // initially modal is hidden
        }
    }

    /**
     * This will toggle the modal state
     * if modal is hidden, it will open the modal
     * else is will close the modal
     */
    toggleUserModal = ()=>{
        this.setState((state)=>{
            return{
                isModalOpen: !state.isModalOpen
            }
        })
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Container>
                <Row>
                    <Col>
                        <div className='mt-3'>
                            <Button onClick={this.toggleUserModal} outline color="secondary">Create User</Button>
                            {this.state.isModalOpen ?
                                <UsersModal
                                    onClose={this.toggleUserModal}
                                />
                                :null}
                        </div>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            </Container>
        )
    }
}

export default Users
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a boolean attribute inside your User component, like `modalOpen`, then render it conditionally in the DOM when you set `modalOpen` to `true`

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './Users.css';
import { Container, Row, Col, Button } from 'reactstrap';
import UsersModal from '../../Components/UsersModal/UsersModal';

class Users extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.state = {
             modalOpen: false,
        }
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <Container>
                <Row>
                    <Col>
                        <div className='mt-3'>
                            <Button outline color="secondary">Create User</Button>
                            {modalOpen ? <UsersModal></UsersModal> : ''}
                        </div>
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            </Container>
        )
    }
}

export default Users
```

Now your Users component has the power to switch on/off on the modal view. You can do this by calling `this.setState({...this.state, modalOpen: true)`